# Display error when executing the "react-native run-android" command

Tags: java, android, react-native

An error is displayed when I run react-native run-android

```
error failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of 'emulator list.awds'.
```

[image: Valid XHTML]

But in Android Studio, the program runs on nox emulator without any problems
It is also known as an emulator in adb, but it still displays when not running react-native run-android.

Comment: Check in the console --> adb devices

Comment: Did you manage to solve it in the end?